# Publishing existing Mapbox Vector Tiles using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles

I am new to Geoserver so it's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious. 
I have a large set of vector tiles created by another process in a complex workflow, and I would like to publish them as a service. I found [this tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html) 
but it mostly pertains to publishing vector tiles from existing layers and doesn't really touch upon my situation, where the vector tiles have been created for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html) makes clear the Vector tiles module is an output format not a datasource, so it is currently impossible for GeoServer to read in vector tiles.

If you would like to add this functionality to GeoTools (Datasources are implemented in GeoTools):
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

If you want to contribute money instead of time/skill, see here:
http://geoserver.org/support/

Comment: Or perhaps a pre-seeded cache could be published with GeoWebCache like it can publish ArcGIS caches http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/arcgistilingschemes.html?

Comment: that could also work but would probably still need new code in GT as well as GWC